# On the possible aspect of an action expressed by an infinitive clause

Tags: grammar, infinitive

Below I quote a sentence from a book:

> Immer wieder glaubte sie, einzelne Wörter aus der Unterhaltung der Damen herauszuhören, doch drang nichts an ihr Ohr, was einen Sinn ergeben hätte.

In the first clause, *glauben* has an infinitive clause as its object, in the stead of an alternative *dass* clause, which would be *dass sie einzelne Wörter aus der Unterhaltung der Damen heraushörte*.

I suppose in this *dass* clause the action *heraushören* is of imperfect aspect, i.e. the action was still going on. Is this assumption correct?

If this assumption is correct, then the infinitive clause would convey an imperfect aspect as well as the *dass* clause because it is no more than a contraction of the *dass* clause; but this seems curious to me because I presume the infinitive always represents the aorist rather than any other aspect.

Could anyone help dispel this confusion?

Comment: "Immer wieder" definitively hints to an imperfect. And you are working on a different sentence than the original - There's no "dass" in there... I don't think both say the same thing (depending on whether you consider *heraushörte* in your replacement subjunctive or not.)

Comment: What is an aorist?

Comment: @Em1 : thanks for your attention ; if an action or event is represented with the aorist aspect, it is perceived as a simple , integral entity with any possible inner structure or process being left out of consideration.

Comment: @tofro : thanks for your comment ; I am wondering whether the infinitival clause herein, which is quite contracted, could be expanded / restored into a COMPLETE subordinate clause with its meaning unaltered? My previous attempt at such clause-expansion seems unsuccessful because the meaning has been altered, so could you give one that does properly preserves the meaning?

Comment: I usually perceive the infinitive as neutral in that respect; it conveys neither the aorist aspect as in Greek (it doesn't have to be a single completed action in the past), nor a present aspect, nor a past aspect. The aspect, if any, is derived from the context.

Comment: @Em1: An aspect in some languages; see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aorist

Answer (score 2):

German does not have aspects. Therefore, your assumption that “the infinitive always represents the aorist rather than any other aspect” is wrong, making your other points moot.

Still, the actions of *glauben* and *heraushören* are indeed perceived as happening at the same time, but the reason for this is one of tense: In such clauses, this is what the present infinitive indicates. The past infinitive, instead, indicates that its action happened earlier than that of the main clause.

> Sie glaubte, einzelne Wörter herauszuhören.
>   Sie glaubte, einzelne Wörter herausgehört zu haben.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer ; I am wondering whether the infinitival clause herein, which is quite contracted, could be expanded or restored into a COMPLETE subordinate clause with its meaning unaltered? Could you give one such complete subordinate clause if it is possible to do so?

Comment: is such simultaneity between an infinitival clause and the verb that governs it applies in general (beyond this special case of ,,glauben'' herein)?